# global name 'DataFile' is not defined

Tags: django, django-models

```
class PageImages(models.Model):
page  = models.ForeignKey(Pages, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
data  = models.FileField(blank=True)
image = models.CharField(max_length=100)
count = models.IntegerField(default = 10)
def __str__(self):
    return self.image

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DataFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    filename = self.data.url
```

I get error while submit form from django-admin. exception global name 'DataFile' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of super() function is class. You need to pass current class to it:

```
super(PageImages, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also in [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) you can use it without arguments:

```
super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

For class calling super class method should use `super(type, obj)`.

> **type**: type of class here -> PageImages
>      **obj**: you can use `self`